# javascript button repeat action in other button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$(document).on("click", "#button1", function (event) {
    $("#container").load("page1.php");
}

$(document).on("click", "#button2", function (event) {
    $("#container").load("page2.php");
}
```

Hi everybody!
My problem is loading more then ones button action. How it is like this.
When i click `button1` the `page1.php` is loading there is no problem but without refreshing the page when i click `button2` the `page2.php` loading two times, when I click again it is loading 3 times...

I want to load only one time. I check from inspect element 
`event.preventDefault();` is not solve this problem...

Comment: `page2.php` contains same code...???

Comment: If all of these pages contain the same code, they will continue to execute the same code. Producing more and more eventListeners

Comment: probably, you would be binding events more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).off('click').on("click", "#button1", function (event) {
   $("#container").load("page1.php");
}

$(document).off('click').on("click", "#button2", function (event) {
   $("#container").load("page2.php");
}
```

Comment: Don't encourage OP to bind events more than once. He would follow the same way(unbinding and binding events) of coding in future code also.

Comment: Or maybe use page fragment: `$("#container").load("page1.php body");` if script is defined in head part. But if you want to unbind click event, at least namespace it

Comment: I add off('click') before on('click') It work Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
            $(document).on("click", "#button1", function (event) {
            $("#container").load("page1.php");
            });

            $(document).on("click", "#button2", function (event) {
            $("#container").load("page2.php");
            });
```

Are you tags closed properly?
The closing curly braces needs to have a closing bracker followed by the semi colon.